# CentOS server can't be reached from local net after no active request to outer net for some time

Tags: centos

I'm setting Wake-On-Lan of my CentOS server so that it can be wake up through Internet. I set a static ip address on my server, preserve the ip address on the router and create a static ARP entry of the ip and MAC address of my server.

The problem is, if no active request from my server to outer net, after a few minutes, I will not be able to reach my server in the local network through SSH, ping, etc. And the server can be reached right after I delete the static ARP entry on the router.

If I keep 'ping' some website on my server(say, google.com), the server can always be reached whether I bind the static ARP entry or not. I delete the static ARP entry on the router, and I can find my server's ip and MAC on the router's active ARP client page if my server is 'ping' some website. If I let my server stay idle and don't do anything, after a few minutes, my server's entry will disappear from the router's active ARP client page. In the meantime, I can still reach my server if I don't active the ARP binding entry on the router.

Where am I doing wrong? I checked the ARP binding entry a thousand times and I'm pretty sure I didn't fill the wrong ip address and MAC address.

I'm using CentOS 7, the network setup file are as follows:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
# ====== static ip setup =======
IPADDR=192.168.10.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.10.1
DNS1=192.168.10.1
NM_CONTROLLED=no
# ==============================
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp0
UUID=869753b9-240b-445b-5412-98d88dff542a
DEVICE=enp0
ONBOOT=yes
```

`ethtool enp1s0` shows the following:

```
[root@192 network-scripts]# ethtool enp1s0
Settings for enp1s0:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
            1000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: yes
```

Comment: What do you mean by "preserve the ip address on the router" ? Have you set up port-forwarding?  Do you have  a static IP address allocated (by your service provider)? If you don't have a static IP address, then you'll need some form of dynamic DNS instead. That's all you need to do.  You don't need to mess with ARP at all.

Comment: @garethTheRed, "preserve the ip address on the router" means "a static IP address allocated", the reason I want to bind the ARP is that WOL on my server can only take effect if you send the magic pack soon after you shut down the server. if you shutdown the server and leave it for a period of time(say, one night), the server will not respond to your magic pack. I searched on the Internet and someone say it is because the ARP cache of the router, after you shutdown for a period of time, the router will refresh the ARP cache so that it can't find the server for the ip and mac you give

Comment: @garethTheRed  http://networking-forum.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=19163&view=next      Only by creating an ARP entry can I let the router remember the ip and MAC address after my server shutdown

Comment: @garethTheRed  simply adding a static IP address in DHCP is not enough, the DHCP can only assign the IP to specific PC after this PC get on line. If this PC is shutdown, it's IP and MAC is removed from the router's DHCP and router will not know where to send the magic pack

Comment: You make it sound as though the problem is that the router doesnt handle static arp entries. Can you use `tcpdump` on some other computer on the same subnet to see who is not handling the arps? For WOL, you don't need a mac address on the magic packet, you can send it as a broadcast. The mac address used is in the udp data not the ethernet header.

Comment: I now understand what you are trying to do.  Getting your router to remember ARP entries is a bit of a kludge.  The correct way would be to use subnet directed broadcast, but that is probably disabled on your router as it has security implications. Instead, why don't you have something like a Raspberry Pi or an old Linksys router flashed with OpenWRT running permanently on your LAN and `ssh` into that from the Internet. From there, you could then send the WoL packet to your main computer.

Comment: @meuh : I'm thinking about if there is something wrong with my network setup on the CentOS server, for it seems the server stop contacting the router when it's idle. By the way, my router disabled subnet broadcast from outer net, in the port-forwarding page, it doesn't allow the last 3 numbers to be 255

Comment: @garethTheRed : You are right, my router disabled subnet directed broadcast, and my router is not supported officially by OpenWRT. I'll try to flash the router carefully. It seems to be the only way. Thanks~

Comment: @garethTheRed : But I still believe there is something to do with my server's network setup, because when other windows PC connect the router, they all appear in the router's ARP client list, only this CentOS server, after leave it idle for sometime, it will disappear from the ARP client list. Seems it stops contacting the router when it's idle

Comment: The router doesn't know one client from another and will drop entries from the ARP table after a predetermined time for all of them.  However, Windows in notoriously chatty, and maybe this chatter is updating the router's ARP table often enough for it to seem as if they are permanent, whereas the CentOS machine is less chatty and consequently the router drops it from its ARP table.  Just a guess though!

Comment: Perhaps the interface has negociated "energy efficiency" and it doesnt work well. Check `sudo ethtool --show-eee enp0`, and also [edit] your question with `sudo ethtool enp0`.

Comment: @meuh : I updated my question and you can see the output result. But I'm not be able to execute `ethtool --show-eee enp1s0`, it says `Cannot get EEE settings: Operation not supported`